# How to do parallel concurrent HTTP requests

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing, gevent

I have a list of 100 ids, and I need to do a lookup for each one of them. The lookup takes approximate 3s to run. Here is the sequential code that would be needed to run it:

```
ids = [102225077, 102225085, 102225090, 102225097, 102225105, ...]
for id in ids:
    run_updates(id)
```

I would like to run ten (10) of these concurrently at a time, using either gevent or multiprocessor. How would I do this? Here is what I tried for gevent but it's quite slow:

```
def chunks(l, n):
    """ Yield successive n-sized chunks from l.
    """
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]

ids = [102225077, 102225085, 102225090, 102225097, 102225105, ...]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for list_of_ids in list(chunks(ids, 10)):
    jobs = [gevent.spawn(run_updates(id)) for id in list_of_ids]
    gevent.joinall(jobs, timeout=200)
```

What would be the correct way to split up the ids list and run ten-at-a-time? I would even be open to using multiprocessor or gevent (not too familiar with either).

Doing it sequentially takes 364 seconds for 100 ids.

Using multiprocessor takes about 207 seconds on 100 ids, doing 5 at a time:

```
pool = Pool(processes=5)
pool.map(run_updates, list_of_apple_ids)
```

Using gevent takes somewhere in between the two:

```
jobs = [gevent.spawn(run_updates, apple_id) for apple_id in list_of_apple_ids]
```

Is there any way I can get better performance than the Pool.map? I have a pretty decent computer here with a fast internet connection, it should be able to do it much quicker...

Comment: good tutorial  here on multiprocessing http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) library. You can do something like:

```
import grequests


for list_of_ids in list(chunks(ids, 10)):
    urls = [''.join(('http://www.example.com/id?=', id)) for id in list_of_ids]
    requests = (grequests.get(url) for url in urls)
    responses = grequests.map(requests)

    for response in responses:
        print response.content
```

I know this breaks your model somewhat because you have your request encapsulated in a `run_updates` method, but I think it may be worth exploring nonetheless.

Comment: I'm not just fetching a url, I'm actually doing an API call to the iTunes store, so I can't just do a GET.

Answer (score 0):

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from random import Random.random

ids = [random() for _ in range(100)] # make some fake ids, whatever

def do_thing(arg): 
    print arg # Here's where you'd do lookup 

while ids: 
    curs, ids = ids[:10], ids[10:]
    procs = [Process(target=do_thing, args=(c,)) for c in curs]
    for proc in procs: 
        proc.run()
```

This is roughly how I'd do it, I guess.

Comment: When do you actually call `do_thing` ??

Comment: Sorry, I'd called it `printo` in a previous bit of code that I straight copied that from, so what you saw was a sort of bastardized hodgepodge. I've edited it to fix, sorry for any confusion.